# Passing parameters to PowerShell from bat file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm desperately trying to pass parameters from a batch file to a PowerShell script which checks if Windows services are running or not.

Here is my fully operational command:

```
.\nsrservices.ps1 -cmd running nsrexecd,stisvc
```

But the problem is the behaviour of the command :

- In a PowerShell window, the service names are seen as two (or more), thus checking for 'nsrexecd' then checking for 'stisvc'
- In the batch file, the service names are passed to PowerShell as a unique value, thus checking for 'nsrexecd,stisvc'

Here is my bat file :

```
powershell.exe -File .\nsrservices.ps1 -cmd running nsrexecd,stisvc
ECHO.%ERRORLEVEL%
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

In my PS file, parameters are defined like that :

```
param([string]$cmd=$(throw "Type d'action manquante !"),[string[]]$srv)
```

In a log file, I've got these two results (sorry for the French output).

From the PowerShell window:

```
24/12/2015 09:02:50-Paramètres appelés : cmd=running srv=stisvc nsrexecd
24/12/2015 09:02:50-Début test de l'état running du service : stisvc
24/12/2015 09:02:50-    Début évaluation de l'état du service : stisvc
24/12/2015 09:02:50-    Fin évaluation de l'état du service : stisvc
24/12/2015 09:02:50-Le service tourne
24/12/2015 09:02:50-Fin test de l'état running du service : stisvc
24/12/2015 09:02:50-Début test de l'état running du service : nsrexecd
24/12/2015 09:02:50-    Début évaluation de l'état du service : nsrexecd
24/12/2015 09:02:50-    Fin évaluation de l'état du service : nsrexecd
24/12/2015 09:02:50-Le service tourne
24/12/2015 09:02:50-Fin test de l'état running du service : nsrexecd
```

Which means that services are tested sequentially

From the .bat file :

```
24/12/2015 09:04:24-Paramètres appelés : cmd=running srv=nsrexecd,stisvc
24/12/2015 09:04:24-Début test de l'état running du service : nsrexecd,stisvc
24/12/2015 09:04:24-    Début évaluation de l'état du service : nsrexecd,stisvc
24/12/2015 09:04:24-        Le service nsrexecd,stisvc n'existe pas !
24/12/2015 09:04:24-    Fin évaluation de l'état du service : nsrexecd,stisvc
24/12/2015 09:04:24-Fin test de l'état running du service : nsrexecd,stisvc
```

Which means that the service named 'nsrexecd,stisvc' does not exist.

The comma between my two names seems to cause confusion when using a .bat file

So I'm pulling my last hairs to find a workaround to win against this bloody .bat file.

I've tried quotes, single-quote, -File, -Command, but no success.

Any clue or solution would be very appreciated since my research on this forum hasn't given me something usable.

And of course, after that I would like to call the .bat file with parameters.

Comment: One thing you could do is not use commas in the batch call and the change your param for $srv to `ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true`. You can see more here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx. Or just bring it in as a single string and use `-split ","`

Comment: Why call a PowerShell script from a batch file? Just run it directly from PowerShell.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : My question was about including PowerShell in a .bat file because I must. This script is launched from a running program which does not accept other things than .bat and .cmd files...

Comment: `.cmd` and `.bat` files are not independently executable; you have to run them using `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart : sorry, I wanted to say that my program was only able to launch cmd.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I'll use :

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$true,
           ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
[String[]]
$services
```

Your batch call will look like this

```
powershell.exe -File .\nsrservices.ps1 -cmd running nsrexecd stisvc
```

For more details have a look to [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx)

Comment: Great solution; from what I can tell, this is the only way to directly pass an array of values from outside of PowerShell. One thing worth noting: with this approach you actually _must not_ use the parameter _name_ in the invocation (`-services`, here) .

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I've changed my way.
Since I had service names with spaces (and I had to include my .ps1 in a .bat file), I've decided to put parameters control in the main and just leaving the

```
param([string]$cmd,[string[]]$srv)
```

line with no controls.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score -1):

To call upon a PowerShell script from a BAT file I normally do

```
PowerShell .\script.ps1 -arg 1234 -arg2 5678
```

or

```
PowerShell C:\path\to\script.ps1 -arg 1234 -arg2 5678
```

Your PowerShell script file should have something like

```
param([string]$arg, [string]$arg2)
```

at the very top and start of the script.

In my param([string]$arg, [string]$arg2), I defined the switch names as arg and arg2 respectively. So the BAT file will assign anything after -arg to $arg and anything after -arg2 to $arg2.

We can change this to something more convenient depending on your script so for example in the PowerShell script we can change it to

```
param([string]$computer, [string]$filename)
```

and in our BAT file we can call upon PowerShell the same as above but instead of -arg and -arg2, we will use -computer and -filename.

Keep in mind that it's order specific, so you can call upon the script with the arguments like

```
PowerShell .\script.ps1 -computer MyComputer -filename MyFileName
```

or

```
PowerShell .\script.ps1 -filename MyFileName -computer MyComputer
```

-filename will always go to $filename

-computer will always go to $computer.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The OP already knows how to invoke a PS script from a batch file _in general_, as shown in the question. His problem is specifically with an _array_ parameter, which your answer doesn't address.
Also, parameter names are _not_ case-sensitive in PowerShell.